# Dissolve overlapping polygons in R

Tags: r, merge, dissolve

Is there an analogue of ArcGIS Dissolve function in R? I need to dissolve the overlapping polygons and create a single part object.

I was trying to use `gUnionCascaded`, but it creates a multipart object. Is there a function in R to do Multipart to singlepart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `unionSpatialPolygons()` from the `maptools` package?