# Using sf to combine polygons that share borders?

Tags: r, sf

I have rows of respondents with their residential census tract polygon and am trying to generate first-order aggregated areas. Meaning I want a given respondent’s census tract polygon to be merged with all the polygons touching its borders. A separate file contains all possible US census tract polygons.

st_union seems appropriate only for aggregating together ALL interesting polygons to a single mass polygon.

Using st_intersection and then aggregating by row ID seems viable, but I’m unsure how to do the aggregation procedure.

I hope to remain within the sf environment.

Similar threads I’ve quered:
[Dissolve only overlapping polygons in R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/206893/dissolve-only-overlapping-polygons-in-r/321259?noredirect=1#comment522831_321259)

[Joining polygons in R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/63577/joining-polygons-in-r/273515)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understood correctly, given a polygon layer with N features, what you need is to generate a new set of N geometries where each geometry is the result of a union with it's neighbors.

A straightforward solution can be to use a `for` loop going over the 1:N polygons, applying `st_union` on the current set of neighbors for polygon `i` in each "round", as in -

```
geom = list()
for(i in 1:nrow(pol)) {
  geom[[i]] = st_union(pol[pol[i, ], ])
}
geom = do.call(c, geom)
```

Where `pol` is the original layer and `geom` is the new set of merged geometries.

Here is a reproducible example using the `nc` dataset -

```
library(sf)

# Sample data
nc = st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))

# Plot 1
plot(st_geometry(nc))
plot(st_geometry(nc[25, ]), add = TRUE, col = "red")

# Merging each polygon with its neighbors
geom = list()
for(i in 1:nrow(nc)) {
  geom[[i]] = st_union(nc[nc[i, ], ])
}
geom = do.call(c, geom)

# Plot 2
plot(geom)
plot(geom[25], add = TRUE, col = "red")
```

Plot 1 shows the original layer, with a specific polygon n=25 shown in red -

[image]

Plot 2 shows the layer with the new geometries, where the new polygon n=25 is merged with its neighbors -

[image]

Comment: Your `pol` is not defined (as in, running your code produces an error).

Comment: The first code section is to illustrate the concept, it's not reproducible. The second code section is a specific (reproducible) example.

Answer (score 6):

After hours of trying, I made a simple function that merges units by some grouping variable, which is usually what one wants to do.

```
> library(sf)
> library(plyr)
> #load nc data
> nc = st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
Reading layer `nc' from data source `/home/emil/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/sf/shape/nc.shp' using driver `ESRI Shapefile'
Simple feature collection with 100 features and 14 fields
geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -84.32385 ymin: 33.88199 xmax: -75.45698 ymax: 36.58965
epsg (SRID):    4267
proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=NAD27 +no_defs
> #what we want to merge
> plot(st_geometry(nc))
> plot(st_geometry(nc[1:2, ]), add = TRUE, col = "red")
> plot(st_geometry(nc[-(1:2), ]), add = TRUE, col = "green")
```

[image]

```
> #merge units as desired by group variable
> st_union_by = function(geo, group) {
+   # browser()
+   geo
+   group
+ 
+   y2 = list()
+   #loop over by groups and merge units
+   for (i in unique(group)) {
+     #which units
+     z = geo[group == i]
+ 
+     #merge
+     y = Reduce(st_union, z)
+     y2[[i]] = y
+   }
+ 
+   st_sfc(y2)
+ }
> #add grouping variable
> nc$x = c(rep(1, 2), rep(2, 98))
> nc$x
  [1] 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
 [68] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
> #merge
> nc2_geo = st_union_by(nc$geometry, nc$x)
> #plot results
> plot(nc2_geo)
> plot(st_geometry(nc2_geo[1]), add = TRUE, col = "red")
> plot(st_geometry(nc2_geo[2]), add = TRUE, col = "green")
```

[image]

```
> #make a new sf df
> nc2 = plyr::ddply(nc, "x", function(d) {
+   data.frame(
+     AREA = sum(d$AREA)
+   )
+ })
> #make sf df like originally
> st_geometry(nc2) = nc2_geo
> nc2
Simple feature collection with 2 features and 2 fields
geometry type:  GEOMETRY
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: -84.32385 ymin: 33.88199 xmax: -75.45698 ymax: 36.58965
epsg (SRID):    NA
proj4string:    NA
  x   AREA                       geometry
1 1  0.175 POLYGON ((-81.47276 36.2343...
2 2 12.451 MULTIPOLYGON (((-81.76536 3...
> plot(nc2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps `sf` has moved on a bit since 2019, but I think there's a more natural way to achieve this now, without a special function. `summarise` drops a lot of variables, so you need to think about how you want to combine them; here `AREA` is summed, by way of example.

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
#load nc data
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
nc$x <- c(rep(1, 2), rep(2, 98))
nc2 <- nc %>% 
  group_by(x) %>% 
  summarise(geometry = st_union(geometry),
            AREA = sum(AREA))
plot(nc2, max.plot = 1)
```

Comment: I used `geom = st_union(geom)` and that worked too