# Dissolve only overlapping polygons in R using sf

Tags: r, union, sf

I extracted information from open street map that contains many polygons, some of them overlapping. I want to union all polygons that overlap with other polygons. This question has been asked before here: [Dissolve only overlapping polygons in R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/206893/dissolve-only-overlapping-polygons-in-r) but I am looking for an approach that uses the sf package.

Here is a reproducible example:

```
sq = function(pt, sz = 1) st_polygon(list(rbind(c(pt - sz), c(pt[1] + sz, pt[2] - sz), c(pt + sz), c(pt[1] - sz, pt[2] + sz), c(pt - sz))))
x = st_sf(box = 1:6, st_sfc(sq(c(4.2,4.2)), sq(c(0,0)), sq(c(1, -0.8)), sq(c(0.5, 1.7)), sq(c(3,3)), sq(c(-3, -3))))
plot(x)
st_overlaps(x)
```

What I am looking for is an appproach that unions the 2 rectangles that show overlap and the 3 rectangles that have overlap. Problem is that I do not know how to identify the 3 clusters of rectangles that I have in my example. With this information, I can run group_by %>% summarize() on the result and solve my problem.

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Here's my sample data:

```
> plot(bdf)
```

[image]

If you only care about whether polygons overlap and how they form clusters, then use `st_intersects`:

```
> st_intersects(bdf,bdf)
Sparse geometry binary predicate list of length 6, where the predicate was `intersects'
 1: 1
 2: 2, 3, 4
 3: 2, 3, 4
 4: 2, 3, 4
 5: 5, 6
 6: 5, 6
```

That gets you some of the way. The output above can be used to form an adjacency matrix of overlaps, which you can then feed into the `igraph` package to create a graph, and then you can get the disconnected subgraphs.

```
> library(igraph)
> g = st_intersects(bdf,bdf)
> plot(graph_from_adj_list(g))
```

[image]

Find the connected components with `components`:

```
> G = graph_from_adj_list(g)
> components(G)
$membership
[1] 1 2 2 2 3 3

$csize
[1] 1 3 2

$no
[1] 3
```

The `$membership` element of that list is telling you which cluster each of the six original features is a member of, in order.

Alternatively if you do want to construct the geometry of the clusters, use `st_union`:

```
> parts = st_cast(st_union(bdf),"POLYGON")
```

The output of `st_union` is a `"MULTIPOLYGON"` of three, so I split it into its `"POLYGON"` parts and then test intersection with the original features:

```
> st_intersects(bdf, parts)
Sparse geometry binary predicate list of length 6, where the predicate was `intersects'
 1: 1
 2: 3
 3: 3
 4: 3
 5: 2
 6: 2
```

which tells me that original feature 1 is in cluster 1, features 2 to 4 are in cluster 3, and features 5 and 6 form cluster 2.

Note the order is different from the `igraph` example - the ordering of the polygons from the `st_union` is not the same as the ordering of the connected components in the `igraph` example. From lower-left to upper right `st_union` has indexed the clusters 1,3,2 and `igraph` has indexed them 1,2,3. This ordering is arbitrary (but don't mix them up).

Answer (score 4):

These are great solutions. I used your second approach to solve my question above using the example I provide below. I determine the clusters, join them with the data and use group_by to union the polygons in the three clusters. Also added a paste statement to keep the names of the original polygons, something I need for my application:

```
sq = function(pt, sz = 1) st_polygon(list(rbind(c(pt - sz), c(pt[1] + sz, pt[2] - sz), c(pt + sz), c(pt[1] - sz, pt[2] + sz), c(pt - sz))))
x = st_sf(box = 1:6, st_sfc(sq(c(4.2,4.2)), sq(c(0,0)), sq(c(1, -0.8)), sq(c(0.5, 1.7)), sq(c(3,3)), sq(c(-3, -3))))
plot(x)

parts <- st_cast(st_union(x),"POLYGON")
plot(parts)

clust <- unlist(st_intersects(x, parts))

diss <- cbind(x, clust) %>%
  group_by(clust) %>%
  summarize(box = paste(box, collapse = ", "))

plot(diss[1])
```

[image]

Unfortunately, it seems that my actual data from Open Street Map is more messy than the example. When I use st_intersects to determine the links between the features and the clusters it appears that features can be related to two (or more) clusters. I do not understand how this is possible as then these two clusters should be regarded as one cluster.

The data can be found here. Perhaps you can have a look?

https://www.dropbox.com/s/4n259yhh5swqgf2/osm_data.rds?dl=0

Answer (score 1):

I just found a simpler and faster way of doing it with `terra`. Seems to work for complex cases too.

```
if(!require("Require")){
  install.packages("Require")
}
library("Require")
Require("sf")
Require("terra")

sq <- function(pt, sz = 1) st_polygon(list(rbind(c(pt - sz), c(pt[1] + sz, pt[2] - sz), c(pt + sz), c(pt[1] - sz, pt[2] + sz), c(pt - sz))))
x1 <- st_sf(ID = 1:3, Class = c("A", "B", "C"), 
            geometry = st_sfc(sq(c(4.2,4.2)), sq(c(0,0)), sq(c(-3, -3))))
x2 <- st_sf(ID = 4:6, Class = c("B", "A", "A"),
            geometry = st_sfc(sq(c(0.5, 1.7)), sq(c(3,3)), sq(c(1, -0.8))))
x1 <- vect(x1)
x2 <- vect(x2)
plot(x1)
plot(x2)

x <- union(x1, x2)
x <- aggregate(x, by = "Class", dissolve = TRUE)
plot(x, col = c("red", "yellow", "blue"))
```

The advantage is that features that have different Classes will not be unified (which is important in my case). Hope it helps others out there!